# Is there a natural number $n$ for which $\sqrt[n]{22-10\sqrt7}=1-\sqrt7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Is there a natural number $n$ for which $$\sqrt[n]{22-10\sqrt7}=1-\sqrt7$$
My idea was to try to express $22-10\sqrt7$ as something to the power of $2$, but it didn't work $$22-10\sqrt7=22-2\times5\times\sqrt7$$ Since $5^2=25, \sqrt7^2=7$ and $25+7\ne22$. What else can we try?

Comment: You can compute $\left(1-\sqrt7\right)^n$ for small values of $n$ and see for yourself that $\left(1-\sqrt7\right)^3=22-10\sqrt7$.

Comment: You can make the following observation : if $(1-\sqrt{7})^n = 22 - 10\sqrt{7}$, then it will also be true that $(1+\sqrt{7})^n = 22 + 10 \sqrt{7}$ (this is after noticing that $\sqrt 7$ is irrational so one can just compare coefficients and switch the sign of the $\sqrt 7$ term and collect terms from that point on). Then multiplying those two equalities and using the difference-of-squares formula gives $(1^2 - 7)^n = (484 - 700)$, which leads to $(-6)^n = -216$. This leaves precisely one option for integer $n$, namely $n=3$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon But, let $\sqrt[n]{22-10\sqrt7}=\sqrt 2-\sqrt8$ Then, applying the same argument we also have $$(-6)^n=-216\implies n=3$$ :-)

Comment: @lonestudent You're correct, I should have put it as : IF there is a solution to that equation, *then* it must be $3$. But otherwise, you've pointed some very important out.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Then your comment is the fastest solution method.  I already voted $\ddot\smile$.

Comment: Since both $\left(1-\sqrt{7}\right)$ and $\left(22-10\sqrt{7}\right)$ are negative values, $n$ is an odd natural number. Therefore, $\left(\sqrt{7}-1\right)$ = $\left(10\sqrt{7}-22\right)^n$ is also true. Then, we can log both sides to obtain $\log{\left(\sqrt{7}-1\right) } = n\log{\left(10\sqrt{7}-22\right) }$. Finally, $n=\cfrac{0.6490926292 }{0.2163642097 }=3.000000000$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To paraphrase the excellent answer given in the comments:

Because $\sqrt{7}$ is a pure quadratic surd, if there is such a natural number $n$, then also
$$\sqrt[n]{22+10\sqrt{7}}=1+\sqrt{7}.$$
As $(1+\sqrt{7})(1-\sqrt{7})=1^2-\sqrt{7}^2=-6$ it follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
-6&=&(1+\sqrt{7})(1-\sqrt{7})\\
&=&\sqrt[n]{22+10\sqrt{7}}\sqrt[n]{22-10\sqrt{7}}\\
&=&\sqrt[n]{(22+10\sqrt{7})(22-10\sqrt{7})}\\
&=&\sqrt[n]{22^2-10^2\sqrt{7}^2}\\
&=&\sqrt[n]{-216}.
\end{eqnarray*}
It is then clear that the only remaining candidate is $n=3$, and a routine verification shows that
$$(1-\sqrt{7})^3=22-10\sqrt{7}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Alternate method : [Binomial theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)**

We have,

$$\begin{align}&\sqrt[n]{22-10\sqrt7}=1-\sqrt7\\
\implies &\left(1-\sqrt 7\right)^n=22-10\sqrt 7\end{align}$$

$22-10\sqrt 7<0$ tells us that, $n$ must be an odd integer. This implies $n≥3$ and $n=2k+1,\thinspace k\in\mathbb Z^{+}$.

> Let, $N(n)$ be the integer part of $\left(1-\sqrt 7\right)^{n}$, such that if $\left(1-\sqrt 7\right)^n=a-\sqrt b$, then $N(n)=a$.

Since $\sqrt 7$ is irrational and  $\forall k\in\mathbb Z^{+}$ we have,

$$\begin{align}N(2k+1)&≥(2k+1)(\sqrt7)^{2k}+1\\
&=7^k(2k+1)+1\\
&≥22.\end{align}$$

Thus, we conclude that if $N(2k+1)=22$, then $k=1$.

This means, if equality $\left(1-\sqrt 7\right)^n=22-10\sqrt 7 $ is possible, then $n=3$.

Finally, we see that $n=3$ gives us the required equality:

$$\left(1-\sqrt 7\right)^3=22-10\sqrt 7.$$

Answer (score -1):

Note that $2.5\lt\sqrt7\lt2.7$, so $-1.7\lt1-\sqrt7\lt-1.5$, while $-5\lt22-10\sqrt7\lt-3$. The only possible integer power of $n$ for which $(1-\sqrt7)^n=22-10\sqrt7$ is $n=3$. (The power cannot be even, since even powers are non-negative, and if $n\ge5$ then $(-1.5)^n\lt-5$.)

This doesn't prove that $n=3$ satisfies the equation, of course. It merely tells us what needs to be checked, namely

$$(1-\sqrt7)^3=1-3\sqrt7+3\cdot7-7\sqrt7=22-10\sqrt7$$